# Create geography polygon from points in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, geography

In my SQL Server (2008 R2) on Azure, there's a table containing a lot of geographical `Points` (latitude/longitude):

```
CREATE TABLE MyPoints
(
  Region uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
  Number int NOT NULL,
  Position geography NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_MyPoints PRIMARY KEY(Region, Number)
)
```

Now I want to create a `Polygon` from this points to determine, which of my stores are located in the area defined by the points.

Is there a native and fast way to build a polygon from the given points in T-SQL? [The solutions I found](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/0ff0e3ec-fcb3-4aaa-9fbc-dbca6186d717) are using the `STGeomFromText`/`STGeomFomWKB` methods to create a polygon, which seems very cumbersome and slow to me.

Something like:

```
SET @POLY = geometry::STPolyFromPoints(SELECT Position FROM MyPoints)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no native function that takes a table as parameter and converts that to a polygon.

Your best is to combine a scalar User Defined Function to concatenate a column of results into a single comma seperated string with the STPolyFromText that you have already read about.

[UDF to Concatenate Column to CSV String](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2007/10/02/t-sql-user-defined-function-to-concatenate-column-to-csv-string.aspx)

[MSDN - STPolyFromText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933922.aspx)

Comment: We're using a function which concatenates the points in their binary representation and call `STGeomFromWKB` on that string. It's fast enough for our purpose, but it's still ugly.

Comment: Another suggestion would be write your own .NET CLR User Defined Function that does take a table parameter (column of actual Geo Points), and returns a Geometry.  I haven't worked with it yet, but the SqlGeometryBuilder looks promising:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometrybuilder.aspx

Comment: AFAIK is there no support for CLR functions on SQL Azure. I thought about that possibility, too.

Comment: Ah bugger, I missed the Azure reference.  Yeah string concatenation is probably your only option right now.  Take a minute and request this feature on SQL Server Connect!  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback

Answer (score 11):

Assuming we have a table full of ordered longs and lats in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LongAndLats](
    [Longitude] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
    [Latitude] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
    [SortOrder] [int] NULL
    )
```

This will convert those points into a polygon:

```
DECLARE @BuildString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @BuildString = COALESCE(@BuildString + ',', '') + CAST([Longitude] AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST([Latitude] AS NVARCHAR(50))
FROM dbo.LongAndLats
ORDER BY SortOrder

SET @BuildString = 'POLYGON((' + @BuildString + '))';  
DECLARE @PolygonFromPoints geography = geography::STPolyFromText(@BuildString, 4326);
SELECT @PolygonFromPoints
```

Some notes:

- The polygon needs to be closed. ie. the first and last point should be the same.
- Should have min 4 points.
- The order of the points are important. It should follow the "left hand/foot rule" (areas lying to the left-hand side of the line drawn between the points are considered to be inside the Polygon)

Comment: I would be curious to know how to do the actual sorting part since your above solution is great. My hang up is how to sort the points in "left hand/foot rule". I am ending up with a polygon that is overlapping on itself because my lat/long ordering is not right.

Comment: example: `DECLARE @geom GEOMETRY = 
'
POLYGON 
((
-116.77953600883484 33.103710174560547
,-117.03299999237061 32.547900199890137
,-117.11846709251404 33.469111442565918

,-117.38499999046326 33.202700138092041
,-117.38700008392334 33.206999778747559
,-117.39700007438660 33.209300041198730
,-116.77953600883484 33.103710174560547
))'

DECLARE @geog GEOGRAPHY = @geom.MakeValid().STUnion(@geom.MakeValid().STStartPoint()).STAsText()
select @geog`

Comment: @Smitty, the ordering should be known before inserting into the `[dbo].[LongAndLats]` table. I am not aware of any way to determine a reliable non-intersecting sort order if the points are not ordered, I don't think its possible because there could be n possible sort orders.

Comment: My situations is I have a series of random lat/long points all over a city. the outer most points (i.e. the ones furthest from the "center") are the ones I'm trying to make a shape/polygon from. I'm building a market boundary from a bunch of random lat/long points basically but i have to "throw out" the points in the middle of the market and just keep the outer most points to create a polygon. I've done this with .Reduce() to some degree but cannot get a valid polygon because my ordering is wrong. I have to think this is a common problem.. how else would you build shape files of countries etc.

Comment: You could use STEnvelope() to create something rough.eg `DECLARE @geom GEOGRAPHY = ' POLYGON (( -116.77953600883484 33.103710174560547 ,-117.03299999237061 32.547900199890137 ,-117.11846709251404 33.469111442565918 ,-117.38499999046326 33.202700138092041 ,-117.38700008392334 33.206999778747559 ,-117.39700007438660 33.209300041198730 ,-116.77953600883484 33.103710174560547 ))';

SET @geom = @geom.MakeValid()
DECLARE @boundingbox geometry = geometry::STGeomFromWKB(@geom.STAsBinary(), @geom.STSrid).STEnvelope();
SELECT geography::STGeomFromWKB(@boundingbox.STAsBinary(), @boundingbox.STSrid);`

Comment: Also have a look at EnvelopeAggregate. `Returns a bounding object for a given set of geography objects.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929145.aspx

Comment: Yeah already went down these paths. They don't really build a true polygon that represents the market. All my markets should be some type (x sides) of polygon. I suppose I will have to settle on the box .STEnvelope() gives me.

Comment: I ended up generating squares with .STEnvelope() and then "poked holes" via .STDifference() in the larger squares where the smaller squares overlapped.

Comment: code here: `while(@CurrMarket is not null)
begin
 declare @ShrinkShape geometry = (select top 1 Shape from blah where Market = @CurrMarket)
 select 
  @ShrinkShape = @ShrinkShape.STDifference(geo2.Shape)
 from blah geo1
  inner join blah geo2 on geo1.Market <> geo2.Market and geo1.Shape.STIntersects(geo2.Shape) = 1
 where geo1.Market = @CurrMarket 
 update blah set Shape = @ShrinkShape where Market = @CurrMarket
 set @CurrMarket = (
  select top 1 Market 
  from #ShrinkMarkets
  where Market > @CurrMarket 
  order by Market
 )
end`